# How to setup custom path for library that angular cli generates?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, monorepo

I want to change the default folder for libs, that I created, right now this folder is "projects" but I want to have a separate directory, for example, "libs" in the root folder, how can I setup this without nx, or other tools for monorepo?

I want to have something like, is it possible?

```
-libs
    ui-button
    ui-input
-projects
    admin
    web
    mobile
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution here https://indepth.dev/posts/1251/how-to-set-up-an-nx-style-monorepo-workspace-with-the-angular-cli-part-1

```
ng config newProjectRoot libs
```

Comment: Guess this post was moved to [the following url](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/how-to-set-up-an-nx-style-monorepo-workspace-with-the-angular-cli-part-1-16b5)